# Could not parse query error while drawing a Motion Chart using Fusion Tables API

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a Motion Chart using Fusion table API. The error message I am receiving is

> Could not parse query.

I had my fusion table format to be text on first column, date on second column, as required by the visualization type. This is my code, underneath.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["motionchart"]});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {

      google.visualization.drawChart({
        "containerId": "scatter",
        "dataSourceUrl": "//www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=",
        "query": "SELECT 'Nationality','Date','StatusofStudentship','Gender','ModeofAdmission','CourseofStudy','ProgrammeofStudy','CGPA','Race','EnglishLanguageProficiency','Disability','ModeofStudy','InternshipLength','SoftskillQuality','HealthSoundness','Employability','DefermentLength','Religion','Mode of Sponsorship',FROM " + "19mRBx3ysm3VfJQ746j8obWldgjxpw1-sBNdQy4kQ#rows:id=1",
        "refreshInterval": 20,
        "chartType": "MotionChart",
        "options": {}
         });

         options['state'] =
        chart.draw(data, {width: 900, height:400});
        '{"colorOption":"4","iconKeySettings":[],"nonSelectedAlpha":0.4,"orderedByX":false,"iconType":"BUBBLE","yAxisOption":"3","uniColorForNonSelected":false,"yZoomedDataMin":150,"dimensions":{"iconDimensions":["dim0"]},"orderedByY":false,"xZoomedIn":false,"yZoomedDataMax":617,"duration":{"multiplier":1,"timeUnit":"D"},"showTrails":true,"xAxisOption":"2","xZoomedDataMax":1200,"time":"1988","xZoomedDataMin":300,"playDuration":15000,"yLambda":1,"sizeOption":"_UNISIZE","yZoomedIn":false,"xLambda":1};';
        options['width'] = 900;
        options['height'] = 400;
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

 </script>
```

Comment: Why is there a JSON string not assigned to anything after your `draw()` call? Also you're extending `options` which is not defined anywhere and passing a plain object `{}` as options property for the `drawChart`. You need to create an options object, set the properties on it and then pass it to `drawChart`.

Comment: Also in `chart.draw(data, {width: 900, height:400});` `data` is undefined.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I improved the title to better reflect your question and made minor formatting changes. As @gillesc mentions its strange that you have JSON string  which is unassigned and  `data` used in `draw`  is undefined. Its better to include the complete code if you code is just a part of it as It will make the code more clear and easier to understand.